# Como devolver el valor que estoy insertando

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hola que tal tengo un problema con este código, cuando inserto el valor de 10% me lo guarda de manera correcta pero al momento de quererlo editar toma el valor de otro parámetro estoy que me vuelvo loco

```
 <tr class="even pointer " >
  <td>
    <div class="descuentos " id="descuento_global_div">Descuento Global</div>
  </td>
  <td class="">
    <?php  
    $place= "";
    if($compra -> co_tipo_descuento=="porcentTot" ){ 
      $place = "%";
    } 
    if($compra -> co_tipo_descuento=="precioTot" ){
      $place = "$";
    }     
    ?>
    <div class="descuentos small" id="contPorcentDesc">
      <input type="text" name="porcentDesc" id="porcentDesc" onblur="totalizar();" 
       class="form-control" 
       placeholder="<?php echo $place; ?>" 
       value="<?php echo $compra->descuento_global; ?>" />
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="medium">
    <div class="short descuentos">
      <input name="descuento_global" id="descuento_global" 
       type="text" onblur="totalizar();" class="form-control" placeholder="$" readonly />
    </div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Formatea e indenta bien el codigo, anda. Se te ha ido para la derecha mucho y nos e ve sin hace rscroll. Tienes un monton de espacios y tabulaciones entre cada linea.

Comment: listo ya esta editada

Comment: No creo que sea por esto, pero en el segundo if no sería mejor si fuera un else if?

Comment: Cuál variable toma otro valor? y que valor toma esta variable?, especifica un poco mas tu pregunta, no se entiende muy bien.

Comment: Lo que hace codigo es lo siguiente, yo ingreso el numero 10 ya en la parte grafica en un campo de descuento, me realiza bien el descuento incluso en la base de datos aparece, pero a la hora de que yo quiero editar toma el valor de la variable descuento_global, que supongamos que es 50 y cuando edito el valor 50 aparece en el campo de donde deberia estar el 10

Comment: Que hace totalizar();?

Comment: ¿Dónde defines $compra?